# Textview changes on AVD but not on smartphone

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, android-virtual-device

I've made an app in wich  when i press a button i clear my TextView with the command

```
textV.setText("")
```

but this only works on my AVD but not on the real smartphone
i use galaxy s4 version 5.0.1
My code is this..it's just many ImageButtons two buttons and a textview ..the onclick of textview is at the end

```
package com.fanis.math;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyResistance extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
View b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12;
Button bok, bclear;
TextView t;
int k = -1;
int[] ar = new int[4];
double n = 0;
double multi=0;
String nString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.resistance);

    b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im1);
    b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im2);
    b3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im3);
    b4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im4);
    b5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im5);
    b6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im6);
    b7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im7);
    b8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im8);
    b9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im9);
    b10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im10);
    b11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im11);
    b12 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.im12);
    bok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    bclear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    b4.setOnClickListener(this);
    b5.setOnClickListener(this);
    b6.setOnClickListener(this);
    b7.setOnClickListener(this);
    b8.setOnClickListener(this);
    b9.setOnClickListener(this);
    b10.setOnClickListener(this);
    b11.setOnClickListener(this);
    b12.setOnClickListener(this);
    bok.setOnClickListener(this);
    bclear.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.im1:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 0; // dianisma pou krataei kathe psifio
        break;
    case R.id.im2:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 1;
        break;
    case R.id.im3:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 2;
        break;
    case R.id.im4:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 3;
        break;
    case R.id.im5:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 4;
        break;
    case R.id.im6:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 5;
        break;
    case R.id.im7:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 6;
        break;
    case R.id.im8:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 7;
        break;
    case R.id.im9:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 8;
        break;
    case R.id.im10:
        k += 1;
        ar[k] = 9;
        break;
    case R.id.im11:
        k += 1;
        multi = 0.01;
        break;
    case R.id.im12:
        k += 1;
        multi = 0.1;
        break;
    case R.id.ok:
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
            n = n + ar[i - 1] * Math.pow(10, k - i);
        }
        if (multi == 0) {
            multi = Math.pow(10, ar[k]);
        }
        n = n * multi;
        nString = String.valueOf(n) + "" + "Ω";
        t.setText(nString);
        break;
    case R.id.clear:
        t.setText("");
        n = 0;
        k = -1;
        multi=0;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Whats the avd version?

Comment: No one can help you with this without seeing the rest of the program, a description of what exactly happens instead, and any log output that is generated.  You might also want to change something else (such as the test that is in the TextView before clearing it) **to be sure that you are actually running the latest version of your code on the phone**.

Comment: the avd version is 4.4.2 when i press the clear button, code inside onclick(view) of clear button is excecuted fine except setText ..however on avd everything'ds fine